# Define all or most of the functions in a class with memoization by name

Tags: ruby

I have several methods with good human names, and I end up having memoization for each one, for example:

```
class MyClass
  def one_good_name
    @one_good_name ||= some good logic ...
  end
end
```

I am looking for one class level method or some one-line way to make it. Instead of defining `@method_name ||=` everywhere, is there some magic like:

```
attr_accessor_memoizied :one_good_name, ...
```

which won't accept any args?

Comment: How do you expect the "some good logic ..." part to be expressed in the method you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend implementing this with the [memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist) ruby gem:

```
require 'memoist'
class MyClass
  extend Memoist
  def one_good_name
    # some good logic ...
  end

  memoize :one_good_name
end
```

Comment: my bad, I did not google right way to find this gem, great, just wish and chances are solution is there, I love the ruby philosophy

Comment: If you are using Ruby 2.1 or newer, you can even just write `memoize def one_good_name; end` since `def` already returns the name of the defined method as a symbol.